# MongoDB groupby distinct sort together

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have mongodb 1 collections structure like this-

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54d34cb314aa06781400081b"), 
"entity_id" : NumberInt(440), 
"year" : NumberInt(2011), 

}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54d34cb314aa06781400081e"), 
"entity_id" : NumberInt(488), 
"year" : NumberInt(2007), 
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54d34cb314aa06781400081f"), 
"entity_id" : NumberInt(488), 
"year" : NumberInt(2008), 
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54d34cb314aa067814000820"), 
"entity_id" : NumberInt(488), 
"year" : NumberInt(2009), 
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("54d34cb314aa067814000827"), 
"entity_id" : NumberInt(489), 
"year" : NumberInt(2009), 
 }
```

so in output i want that i should get "entity_id" with max "year" only .(suppose with "488" entity_id "year" should be 2009).
i have tried writing query

```
$fin_cursor = $db->command(array(
               "distinct" =>"Profit_and_Loss",
               "key" =>'entity_id',
               "query" => array(array('$and'=>$financial_pl_search_array),array('$sort'=>array("year"=>-1))),

               ));
```

in output i want 2 fields "entity_id" and "year".
can anyone suggest me best way of doing it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're better of using [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to do this. It's also a direct method on the collection objects in modern versions of the driver:

```
$result = $db->collection('Profit_and_loss')->aggregate(array(
    array( '$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$entity_id',
        'year' => array( '$max' => '$year' )
    ))
));
```

The `.distinct()` command only runs over a single field. Other forms require JavaScript evaluation as you have noted and run considerably slower than native code.

Comment: thanx for the help . you saved my day. is it possible to add extra query parameter to this aggregate function?

Comment: @user1673091 Look at the documentation for [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) as well as all aggregation pipeline operators and examples in general. There's not much that you cannot do, within reason.

Comment: I added'$match'=>array('entity_id'=>array('$in'=>array_values($Entities))) to above code then its giving error ,"exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field. "

Comment: @user1673091 Post another question if you have more questions. It is also the way that people can clearly see what you are doing and what man be possibly wrong.