# Mongodb Groupby Aggregate and addition query together

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am taking forward my earlier question [MongoDB GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803480/mongodb-groupby-distinct-sort-together/28803601?noredirect=1#comment45882012_28803601)

After using the aggregate function i get what i want ,now i want to add some query parameters to that aggregate function and the query should be applied to result of aggregate 
i.e for example for entity_id "123" , there are 4 years val

"2010","2011","2012","2013"

after applying the aggregate function as per last question  get "2013" with entity id "123" ,which is absolutely correct.

Now i want to add extra query ,which should be like - "entity_id "123" AND year "2013" AND "extra_query".

I tried using $match but it was taking as "entity_id" 123 AND Extra query.

i have 2 collections in my db

collection 1.

```
{
"entity_id":123,
"added_by":"a",
},
{
"entity_id":321,
"added_by":"b",
},
```

and collection 2

```
{
"entity_id":123,
"year":"2014",
"profit_val":2000,
},
{
"entity_id":123,
"year":"2013",
"profit_val":1000,
},
{
"entity_id":123,
"year":"2012",
"profit_val":500,
},
{
"entity_id":123,
"year":"2011",
"profit_val":100000,
},
```

so when i search "profit_val" > 10000 , i get result as "entity_id" = 123 , BUT this result is wrong as i want to look this condition only with max year of the entity.
inshort i want to group by max year , which i already did ,answer given here now i want to add query to this "grouped" result only.

I hope this will make you understand what i am looking for.

Comment: Wow I just broke that one ball of text into paragraphs to make it readable and it still makes no sense. What are you asking here?

Comment: @NeilLunn i have updated the question, hope this will help you to understand the question.

Comment: Not really clearer for the additions. Are you saying you want to find a document with a "profit_val" > 10000 and also "year" = 2013? Cannot see what this even remotely has to do with the last question you asked or how it would apply here. If engish is not your language you might need help from someone else to write your question. I really does not clearly state anything right now.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from the question is you want something like this.

```
> db.collection2.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {
            "year": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$entity_id",
            year: {
                $max: "$year"
            },
            profit_val: {
                $last: "$profit_val"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "profit_val": {
                "$gt": 10000
            }
        }
    }
])
```